How to design a Mealy state diagram of a 2-bit input logic circuit for different logic gates
Z
VHDL Code in Modelsim:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Entity Declaration
entity Logic_Circuit is
    Port (
        A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); -- 2-bit input A
        B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); -- 2-bit input B
        AND_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); -- AND output
        OR_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); -- OR output
        NAND_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); -- NAND output
        NOR_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); -- NOR output
        XOR_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0) -- XOR output
    );
end Logic_Circuit;

-- Architecture Declaration
architecture Behavioral of Logic_Circuit is
begin
    -- Logic Operations
    AND_OUT <= A and B; -- AND Gate
    OR_OUT <= A or B; -- OR Gate
    NAND_OUT <= not (A and B); -- NAND Gate
    NOR_OUT <= not (A or B); -- NOR Gate
    XOR_OUT <= A xor B; -- XOR Gate
end Behavioral;


you already asked this ... what leads you to believe that you'll receive a different response? ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/733082/how-to-design-a-mealy-state-diagram-of-a-logic-circuit-that-has-a-2-bit-input-a

We need to see an attempt at a solution, don't open new questions edit the originals
